# Cross-referencing with sentences? Is there any way for the LaTex to copy a certain segment from another .tex file?

Tags: cross-referencing, text, multiple-files

Suppose there are several paragraphs in A.tex as follows:

> para1: The Kalman filter is an efficient recursive filter that estimates the internal state of a linear dynamic system from a series of noisy measurements. It is used in a wide range of engineering and econometric applications from radar and computer vision to estimation of structural macroeconomic models, and is an important topic in control theory and control systems engineering.

> para2: Together with the linear-quadratic regulator (LQR), the Kalman filter solves the linear–quadratic–Gaussian control problem (LQG). **The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the most fundamental problems in control theory.**

> para3: **In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.** However, by combining a series of measurements, the Kalman filter can estimate the entire internal state.

What I need to do is to  automatically copy the sentences marked with boldface letters (note that the sentences are marked with boldface letters for indication only, i.e., boldface letters should not be the condition for copying) in B.tex, such that in B.tex contains:

> **The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the most fundamental problems in control theory.**

> **In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.**

and these sentences would change if they are modified in A.tex.

What I am trying to say is that, is there any way of referencing those sentences similar to doing the cross-referencing such as citations and equations (e.g., using \label{})?

**Edit on 30-Nov-2020:**

Another thing is that I might need to inlcude some special symbols in the context, such as math symbols $\alpha$.

Comment: Maybe the package [catchfilebetweentags](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/catchfilebetweentags.pdf) can be useful here.

Comment: @ZHUANG Perhaps the [docstrip-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) is of interest to you.  The [docstrip-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) provides the possibility to place tags into a .tex-source-file that begin with `%` and therefore usually look like comments, and to apply docstrip.tex for reading that .tex-source-file and to extract/copy portions of it that are nested between tags to other/newly created .tex-files.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! Will take a look of the package!

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks! I will have a look!

Comment: @ZHUANG Do you need macros for handling cross references occurring in the sentences that are to be copied?  E.g., if a sentence of A.tex, which is to be copied, contains a cross-reference to "chapter 4",  something like "as can be seen in chapter \ref{chap4}...", that cross-reference obviously refers to chapter 4 of document A. You can use the package xr or xr-hyper for importing A's cross-referencing-data to B. But in document B you might probably wish that the textual phrase of the cross-reference also points out that it refers to document A: "as can be seen in chapter 4 of document A...",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) might be your friend:

By means of [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) you can implement your own `\label`-`\ref`-like cross-referencing-mechanisms, e.g., for retrieving and storing sentences. By means of [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s module xr you can retrieve zref-cross-referencing-labels from other .tex-documents as long as the .aux-files of these documents are available.

*I suggest using zref-route because with zref you*

- get warnings on the terminal/in the .log-file about multiply-defined labels if present.
- are informed via terminal/.log-file about the need to re-run LaTeX in case data related to a label/related to something saved has changed.

The following file `A.tex`  uses [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) for providing macros `\StoreSentence` and `\RetrieveSentence` for making a sentence accessible via a zref-cross-referencing-label.

The following file `B.tex`  uses the same things and additionally loads [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s xr-module for making available the zref-cross-referencing-data of `A.tex`/`A.aux` during compilation of `B.tex`.

`A.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \texorpdfstring{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}{??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence[1]{%
      \texorpdfstring{\zref@refused{#1}}{}%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence[1]{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%
\zref@newprop{storedsentence}[\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText]{}%
\@ifdefinable\StoreSentence{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\StoreSentence[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \zref@setcurrent{storedsentence}{#2}%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{storedsentence}%
    \endgroup
    #2%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label FirstSentence in A.tex:

\RetrieveSentence{FirstSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label SecondSentence in A.tex:

\RetrieveSentence{SecondSentence}

\bigskip\noindent\hrule\bigskip

Let's create the labels:

\vfill

This is some text which does not go to a label.

%\textbf{%
  \StoreSentence{FirstSentence}{This is some text which in A.tex went to the label FirstSentence.}%
%}

\vfill

This is some text which does not go to a label.

%\textbf{%
  \StoreSentence{SecondSentence}{This is some text which in A.tex went to the label SecondSentence.}%
%}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Repeating compiling `A.tex` without deleting .aux-files between compilations until messages like

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `A.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
```

and

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

are not displayed on the terminal any more yields `A.pdf`:

[image]

`B.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This time let's load zref's module xr for importing labels from the .aux-files of other documents:
\usepackage[xr]{zref}
% Let's import the zref-cross-referencing-labels from A.tex/A.aux:
%\zexternaldocument[<prefix to add to names of imported labels>]{<external document>}[<url>]
\zexternaldocument[FromA:]{A}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \texorpdfstring{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}{??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence[1]{%
      \texorpdfstring{\zref@refused{#1}}{}%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence[1]{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%
%\zref@newprop{storedsentence}[\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText]{}%
%\@ifdefinable\StoreSentence{%
%  \DeclareRobustCommand\StoreSentence[2]{%
%    \begingroup
%    \zref@setcurrent{storedsentence}{#2}%
%    \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{storedsentence}%
%    \endgroup
%    #2%
%  }%
%}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label FirstSentence in A.tex:

\RetrieveSentence{FromA:FirstSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label SecondSentence in A.tex:

\RetrieveSentence{FromA:SecondSentence}

\end{document}
```

As long as `A.tex` and `A.aux` from repetitive compiling of `A.tex` are available,
repeating compiling `B.tex` without deleting .aux-files between compilations until messages like

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `B.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
```

and

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

are not displayed on the terminal any more yields `B.pdf`:

[image]

---

**Caveats and possible pitfalls:**

- **When you change `A.tex`, you need to compile `A.tex` repetitively to create `A.aux` and `A.pdf` which reflect the changes and then to compile `B.tex` repetitively to create `B.pdf` which reflects the changes in `A.tex`, too.**
- **Commands/control sequences occurring in the text that is to be cross-referable across documents won't be expanded when writing the corresponding data to .aux-file:**

  **If commands/control-sequences (e.g., denoting mathematical symbols) are used in `A.tex` in places that are to be copied, then it must be ensured that these commands/control sequences get defined in `B.tex`, too.** If, e.g., a mathematical symbol in `A.tex` comes from the amssymb-package, then `B.tex`  needs to load that package, too.

  **Numbered items of sectioning denoted by underlying commands/control sequences like `\section{...}` or `\begin{equation}`  will be a problem, too,** because the underlying control sequences, too, won't be expanded.

  In order to resolve this you may need to make every numbered thing cross-referable by placing a `\label` into `A.tex`. Then you can retrieve that data within `B.tex` via the package [xr](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr)/[xr-hyper](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper).

  If you wish to also copy numbered items of sectioning, preserving the numbers, then probably the package [docstrip](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) is the better choice.

  [I posted another answer exhibiting docstrip.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572951)

---

With the examples above in `B.pdf` you have textual phrases coming from `A.tex`/`A.aux`. But you don't have hyperlinks in `B.pdf` leading to the corresponding places in `A.pdf`.

If you need hyperlinks, you can load the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-package and have `\StoreSentence` create a named destination/an anchor and store the name of that destination/anchor within the zref-label.  Then `\RetrieveSentence` can retrieve that information for wrapping everything into a hyperlink. In the examples below the counter `SentenceCounter` is used for auto-generating unique names for the named destinations/anchors. In the examples below the macro `\RetrieveSentence` comes with a "starred variant" which does not create hyperlinks.

`A.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}

% The code between \makeatletter..\makeatother can go into a package/a .sty-file
% of its own. If the hyperref-package shall  be used, then that .sty-file must
% be loaded _after_ the hyperref-package.
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage[xr]{zref}%
\zref@newlist{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}%
\zref@newprop{storedsentence}[\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText]{}%
\zref@addprop{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}{storedsentence}%
\newcounter{SentenceCounter}%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \zref@newprop{NameOfDestination}[]{}%
  \zref@addprop{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}{NameOfDestination}%
  \@ifdefinable\@hashchar{\edef\@hashchar{\string#}}%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \texorpdfstring{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}{??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence{%
      \@ifstar\RetrieveSentenceAtStar\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar[1]{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{\@firstofone}{%
        \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#1}{NameOfDestination}{%
          \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#1}{externaldocument}{%
            \href[pdfnewwindow=true]{%
              \zref@extractdefault{#1}{externaldocument}{}%
              \@hashchar
              \zref@extractdefault{#1}{NameOfDestination}{}%
            }%
          }{%
            \hyperlink{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{NameOfDestination}{}}%
          }%
        }{\@firstofone}%
      }%
    }{\@firstofone}%
    {%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtStar[1]{%
    \texorpdfstring{\zref@refused{#1}}{}%
    \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\StoreSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\StoreSentence[2]{%
      \texorpdfstring{%
        \stepcounter{SentenceCounter}%
        \hypertarget{SentenceDestination.\arabic{SentenceCounter}}{#2}%
        \begingroup
        \zref@setcurrent{storedsentence}{#2}%
        \zref@setcurrent{NameOfDestination}{SentenceDestination.\arabic{SentenceCounter}}%
        \zref@labelbylist{#1}{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}%
        \endgroup
      }{%
        \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence{%
      \@ifstar\RetrieveSentenceAtStar\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtStar[1]{%
    \zref@refused{#1}%
    \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText}%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar[1]{%
    \zref@refused{#1}%
    \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\StoreSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\StoreSentence[2]{%
      \stepcounter{SentenceCounter}%
      #2%
      \begingroup
      \zref@setcurrent{storedsentence}{#2}%
      \zref@labelbylist{#1}{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}%
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label FirstSentence in A.tex with hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence{FirstSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label SecondSentence in A.tex with hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence{SecondSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label FirstSentence in A.tex without hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence*{FirstSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label SecondSentence in A.tex without hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence*{SecondSentence}

\bigskip\noindent\hrule\bigskip

Let's create the labels:

\vfill

This is some text which does not go to a label.

%\textbf{%
  \StoreSentence{FirstSentence}{This is some text which in A.tex went to the label FirstSentence.}%
%}

\vfill

This is some text which does not go to a label.

%\textbf{%
  \StoreSentence{SecondSentence}{This is some text which in A.tex went to the label SecondSentence.}%
%}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

`A.pdf`:

[image]

`B.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}

% The code between \makeatletter..\makeatother can go into a package/a .sty-file
% of its own. If the hyperref-package shall  be used, then that .sty-file must
% be loaded _after_ the hyperref-package.
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage[xr]{zref}%
\zref@newlist{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}%
\zref@newprop{storedsentence}[\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText]{}%
\zref@addprop{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}{storedsentence}%
\newcounter{SentenceCounter}%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \zref@newprop{NameOfDestination}[]{}%
  \zref@addprop{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}{NameOfDestination}%
  \@ifdefinable\@hashchar{\edef\@hashchar{\string#}}%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \texorpdfstring{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}{??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence{%
      \@ifstar\RetrieveSentenceAtStar\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar[1]{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{\@firstofone}{%
        \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#1}{NameOfDestination}{%
          \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#1}{externaldocument}{%
            \href[pdfnewwindow=true]{%
              \zref@extractdefault{#1}{externaldocument}{}%
              \@hashchar
              \zref@extractdefault{#1}{NameOfDestination}{}%
            }%
          }{%
            \hyperlink{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{NameOfDestination}{}}%
          }%
        }{\@firstofone}%
      }%
    }{\@firstofone}%
    {%
      \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtStar[1]{%
    \texorpdfstring{\zref@refused{#1}}{}%
    \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\StoreSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\StoreSentence[2]{%
      \texorpdfstring{%
        \stepcounter{SentenceCounter}%
        \hypertarget{SentenceDestination.\arabic{SentenceCounter}}{#2}%
        \begingroup
        \zref@setcurrent{storedsentence}{#2}%
        \zref@setcurrent{NameOfDestination}{SentenceDestination.\arabic{SentenceCounter}}%
        \zref@labelbylist{#1}{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}%
        \endgroup
      }{%
        \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}{%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence@RefUndefText{%
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\RetrieveSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveSentence{%
      \@ifstar\RetrieveSentenceAtStar\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtStar[1]{%
    \zref@refused{#1}%
    \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText}%
  }%
  \newcommand\RetrieveSentenceAtNoStar[1]{%
    \zref@refused{#1}%
    \zref@extractdefault{#1}{storedsentence}{\RetrieveNumber@RefUndefText}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\StoreSentence{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\StoreSentence[2]{%
      \stepcounter{SentenceCounter}%
      #2%
      \begingroup
      \zref@setcurrent{storedsentence}{#2}%
      \zref@labelbylist{#1}{StoreAndRetrieveSentence}%
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

% Let's import the zref-cross-referencing-labels from A.tex/A.aux:
%\zexternaldocument[<prefix to add to names of imported labels>]{<external document>}[<url>]
\zexternaldocument[FromA:]{A}[./A.pdf] %<- hyperlinks must go to A.pdf !!!

\begin{document}

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label FirstSentence in A.tex with hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence{FromA:FirstSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label SecondSentence in A.tex with hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence{FromA:SecondSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label FirstSentence in A.tex without hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence*{FromA:FirstSentence}

\bigskip

Let's retrieve the sentence associated to the label SecondSentence in A.tex without hyperlink:

\RetrieveSentence*{FromA:SecondSentence}

\end{document}
```

`B.pdf`:

[image]

---

**Caveats and possible pitfalls:**

- **When you change `A.tex`, you need to compile `A.tex` repetitively to create `A.aux` and `A.pdf` which reflect the changes and then to compile `B.tex` repetitively to create `B.pdf` which reflects the changes in `A.tex`, too.**
- **Commands/control sequences occurring in the text that is to be cross-referable across documents won't be expanded when writing the corresponding data to .aux-file:**

  **If commands/control-sequences (e.g., denoting mathematical symbols) are used in `A.tex` in places that are to be copied, then it must be ensured that these commands/control sequences get defined in `B.tex`, too.** If, e.g., a mathematical symbol in `A.tex` comes from the amssymb-package, then `B.tex`  needs to load that package, too.

  **Numbered items of sectioning denoted by underlying commands/control sequences like `\section{...}` or `\begin{equation}`  will be a problem, too,** because the underlying control sequences, too, won't be expanded.

  In order to resolve this you may need to make every numbered thing cross-referable by placing a `\label` into `A.tex`. Then you can retrieve that data within `B.tex` via the package [xr](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr)/[xr-hyper](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper).

  If you wish to also copy numbered items of sectioning, preserving the numbers, then probably the package [docstrip](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) is the better choice.

  [I posted another answer exhibiting docstrip.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572951)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried your method. It would work quite well refering texts, but when it comes to special symbols, such as equations or math symbols, it reports 'Undefined control sequence. \RetrieveSentence{FromA:First}'. Do you think there is a way of including the special symbols?

Comment: It turns out that I need to use all the packages required to insert those symbols. It is now working quite smoothly!

Comment: @ZHUANG I just added an answer exhibiting usage of the docstrip-package. (I couldn't append it to my first answer due to the 30000-character-limit with answers. ;-) )

Answer (score 4):

Create a file `textref.sty` with the following contents:

```
\newcommand\save[2]{%
  \@bsphack\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newtext{#1}{#2}}\@esphack
  \newtext{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand\newtext[2]{\global\@namedef{text:#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\recall[1]{%
  \ifcsname text:#1\endcsname
    \@nameuse{text:#1}%
  \else
    \textbf{??? Unknown Text ???}%
  \fi
}   
\newcommand\saveAndRecall[2]{\save{#1}{#2}\recall{#1}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{xr}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{xr}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\XR@test{\fi\fi\fi}{\else\ifx#1\newtext\let\XR@tempa\@firstoftwo\fi\fi\fi\fi}{}{}
```

`textref.sty` defines three commands:

`\save{label}{text}` ... makes `text` accessible via `label`

`\recall{label}` ... replaces `label` by the corresponding saved `text`

`\saveAndRecall{label}{text}` ... combines the upper two commands, i.e., saves `text` with `label` and prints `text`

Moreover, the package loads the `xr` package; any options passed to `textref` are forwarded to the `xr` package such that its full functionality is available as well.

In the preamble of your documents, load the package with

```
\usepackage{textref}
```

As with `\label` and `\ref`, you have to run (pdf/xe/lua)latex twice to propagate the information.

This works also across file boundaries. You just have to include the foreign `.aux` file in the preamble using

```
\externaldocument{A}
```

Here is an example:

```
% A.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textref}
\begin{document}
\section*{A.tex}
William Shakespeare once wrote: ``\saveAndRecall{hamlet}{Two beer or not two beer!}''.
Or did he?
\end{document}

% B.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textref}
\externaldocument{A}
\begin{document}
\section*{B.tex}
\recall{hamlet}
\end{document}
```

First typeset `A.tex`, then `B.tex`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to implement your way through copy-and-paste. Got 'Argument of \etb@resrvdb has an extra }. ...text\let\XR@tempa\@firstoftwo\fi\fi\fi\fi}', and 'Paragraph ended before \etb@resrvdb was complete. ...text\let\XR@tempa\@firstoftwo\fi\fi\fi\fi}' errors at '\xpatchcmd\XR@test{\fi\fi\fi}{\else\ifx#1\newtext\let\XR@tempa\@firstoftwo\fi\fi\fi\fi}{}{}' in your .sty file. Sorry I am quite new to LaTeX. Could you show me how to fix this?

Comment: @ZHUANG Does my example work for you, when you copy it literally? If not, then you probably need to upgrade your TeX installation. If yes, I'd need to see a minimal example of the failing code. There may be some error elsewhere, or some other package interferes.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I didn't know about the `zref` package and started from scratch. Clearly it is better to use a tested package. Let's wait for ZHANG to come back. Once he has solved his problem with `zref`, I wil delete my solution.

Comment: @gernot No, don't delete your solution!  I like your approach. Doing things from scratch often avoids complicated overhead which is not necessary for the scenario which one has in mind...

Comment: @gernot By the way: Adding checks for already defined/saved things and changed things is easy: Already defined:  Just have your `\newtext` macro check if the macro it shall define is already defined.  Check if things are changed: The .aux-file is read at the begin of the LaTeX-run. Hereby `\newlabel`-entries are carried out. Then it gets destryed and written anew during the LaTeX-run. At the end of the LaTeX-run `\@newl@bel` is let equal to `\@testdef` and the anew-written .aux-file is read. So `\newtext` ...

Comment: @gernot So `\newtext` could check if `\@newl@bel` is equal to `\@testdef`. If not so, we have the .aux-file-reading at the begin of the LaTeX-run, thus act as usual. If so, we have the .aux-file-reading at the end of the LaTeX-run, thus compare what is written now with the macro - just as `\@testdef` does for `\newlabel`-entries...  You may need `\AtVeryEnd` for calling a macro which by default is a no-op and in case of detecting changes is redefined to print a message about the changes and the need to re-run LaTeX.

Comment: @gernot Sorry for the delay. The errors showed up when I was trying to implement it after a copy-and-paste from your answer here. I will try to upgrade the LaTex (probably this issue). I will update you shortly! Thanks!

Comment: @gernot Forgot to tell I did not update the distribution as it required quite some changes. Your solution is neat but I have turned to the *zref* package. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way closest to what you asked for I can think of would be to concatenate the bold text to a single macro - which will only help you if you want to include A.tex and B.tex in the same project.

Note that this will not create a file B.tex in which all the bold text is written down, but you can use the macro *\myBoldText* at any point of the document in order to display the content.

```
% ## In the header:
% Create an empty macro:
\def\myBoldText{}

% Define how text shall be separated in B.tex
\def\mySeparator{\newline}

% Create a command which appends input text to the macro
\newcommand{\addToMyBoldText}[1]{#1% <- you can modify here to always display bold
\expandafter\def\expandafter\myBoldText\expandafter{\myBoldText\mySeparator #1}}
```

```
% ## In A.tex
... \addToMyBoldText{The Kalman filter ... in control theory} ...
... \addToMyBoldText{In most applications ... are measured} ...
```

```
% ## In B.tex
\myBoldText
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use more or less the same "skeleton"/framework both for `A.tex` and for `B.tex`, then the package [docstrip](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) might be your friend:

The package [docstrip](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) provides the possibility to place tags into a .tex-source-file that begin with `%` and therefore usually look like comments, and to apply `docstrip.tex` for reading that .tex-source-file and by means of the `\generate`-command to extract/copy portions of it that are nested between tags to other/newly created .tex-files.

You can use this for generating different variants of more or less the same document.

If you compile the example `both.tex` below, no .pdf-file will be created but a file `A.tex` and a file `B.tex` will be created with slightly different content.

With the example `both.tex` below, things tagged as

```
%<*A,B>
...
%</A,B>
```

will be processed both when generating `A.tex` and when generating `B.tex`.

Things tagged as

```
%<*A>
...
%</A>
```

will be processed only when generating `A.tex`.

Things tagged as

```
%<*B>
...
%</B>
```

will be processed only when generating `B.tex`.

The nesting of tags is important:

If you do

```
%<*A,B>
This (first) phrase winds up both in A.tex and in B.tex
%<*A>
This (second) phrase winds up in A.tex only.
%</A>
%<*B>
This (third) phrase winds up in B.tex only.
%</B>
%</A,B>
```

, then the statements provided by the phrases are true.

If you do

```
%<*A>
This (first) phrase winds up in A.tex only.
%<*A,B>
This (second) phrase winds up both in A.tex and in B.tex
%</A,B>
%<*B>
This (third) phrase winds up in B.tex only.
%</B>
%</A>
```

, then

- the statement formed by the first phrase is true.
- the statement formed by the second phrase is false because that phrase, too will wind up in `A.tex` only.
- the statement formed by the third phrase is false because that phrase neither will wind up in `A.tex` nor will wind up in `B.tex`.

`both.tex`:

```
%<*ignore>
% Section with docstrip directives for generating different 
% .tex-input-files:
\input docstrip

\declarepreamble\DocumentA
____________________________

Information relevant to A.tex.

\endpreamble

\declarepreamble\DocumentB
____________________________

Information relevant to B.tex.

\endpreamble

\generate{%
  \nopostamble
%
  \usepreamble\DocumentA
  \file{A.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{A}}%
%
  \usepreamble\DocumentB
  \file{B.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{B}}%
}%
% If you can take the risk of compiling  both.tex
% with option "--enable-write18", then here you can probably insert
% \write18-calls suitable for your platform for calling pdflatex
% from console for compiling the files just generated -- something like:
%
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex A.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex B.tex}
%
% or:
%
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify A.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify B.tex}
%
% or:
%
%    \immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf A.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf B.tex}
%
% If LuaTeX-based LaTeX-engines might also be in use, where no "native"
% `\write18` is available:
%
% \RequirePackage{shellesc} % See: https://ctan.org/pkg/shellesc
% %
% \ShellEscape{latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf A.tex}
% \ShellEscape{latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf B.tex}
% ...
\csname stop\endcsname % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)LaTeX
                       %    for generating the files.
%
\bye % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)TeX for generating the 
%    %    files.
%
%</ignore>
% Section containing the actual LaTeX document, with tags for
% generating different variants
%
%<*A,B>
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstOfOne[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{para}{para}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{A section about paras}
%<*A>
\begin{para}
The Kalman filter is an efficient recursive filter that estimates the
internal state of a linear dynamic system from a series of noisy
measurements. It is used in a wide range of engineering and econometric
applications from radar and computer vision to estimation of structural
macroeconomic models, and is an important topic in control theory and
control systems engineering.
\end{para}
%</A>
%<*B>
\stepcounter{para}%
%</B>
\begin{para}
%<*A>
Together with the linear-quadratic regulator (LQR), the Kalman filter
solves the linear–quadratic–Gaussian control problem (LQG).
%</A>
The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–
quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the
most fundamental problems in control theory.
\end{para}
\begin{para}
In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of
freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.
%<*A>
However, by combining a series of measurements, the Kalman filter can
estimate the entire internal state.
%</A>
\end{para}
\begin{para}
The symbol \FirstOfOne{\checkmark} comes from amssymb.
\end{para}
\end{document}
%</A,B>
```

Compiling `both.tex` delivers

`A.tex` with the following content:

```
%%
%% This is file `A.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% both.tex  (with options: `A')
%% ____________________________
%% 
%% Information relevant to A.tex.
%% 
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstOfOne[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{para}{para}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{A section about paras}
\begin{para}
The Kalman filter is an efficient recursive filter that estimates the
internal state of a linear dynamic system from a series of noisy
measurements. It is used in a wide range of engineering and econometric
applications from radar and computer vision to estimation of structural
macroeconomic models, and is an important topic in control theory and
control systems engineering.
\end{para}
\begin{para}
Together with the linear-quadratic regulator (LQR), the Kalman filter
solves the linear–quadratic–Gaussian control problem (LQG).
The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–
quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the
most fundamental problems in control theory.
\end{para}
\begin{para}
In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of
freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.
However, by combining a series of measurements, the Kalman filter can
estimate the entire internal state.
\end{para}
\begin{para}
The symbol \FirstOfOne{\checkmark} comes from amssymb.
\end{para}
\end{document}
```

`B.tex` with the following content:

```
%%
%% This is file `B.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% both.tex  (with options: `B')
%% ____________________________
%% 
%% Information relevant to B.tex.
%% 
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstOfOne[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{para}{para}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{A section about paras}
\stepcounter{para}%
\begin{para}
The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–
quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the
most fundamental problems in control theory.
\end{para}
\begin{para}
In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of
freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.
\end{para}
\begin{para}
The symbol \FirstOfOne{\checkmark} comes from amssymb.
\end{para}
\end{document}
```

Compiling `A.tex` yields `A.pdf`:

[image]

Compiling `B.tex` yields `B.pdf`:

[image]

---

---

If you wish phrases that occur both in `A.tex` and in `B.tex` to be hyperlinks that lead from the one file to the other file, then you can load the packages xr-hyper and hyperref and

- for `A.tex` have an `\externaldocument`-command for importing cross-referencing-labels from `B.tex` and
- for `B.tex` have an `\externaldocument`-command for importing cross-referencing-labels from `A.tex` and
- both wih `A.tex` and with `B.tex` have a command
  `\InterLink{⟨referencing-label⟩}{⟨text⟩}`
  which turns `⟨text⟩` both into a named destination/hypertarget (which can be denoted in the other file's hyperlink) and into a hyperlink (leading to the other file's corresponding named destination).

`both.tex`:

(This time I have added some `\vfill` so when viewing at a large zoom-factor you can test hyperlinks/navigation.)

```
%<*ignore>
% Section with docstrip directives for generating different 
% .tex-input-files:
\input docstrip

\declarepreamble\DocumentA
____________________________

Information relevant to A.tex.

\endpreamble

\declarepreamble\DocumentB
____________________________

Information relevant to B.tex.

\endpreamble

\generate{%
  \nopostamble
%
  \usepreamble\DocumentA
  \file{A.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{A}}%
%
  \usepreamble\DocumentB
  \file{B.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{B}}%
}%
% If you can take the risk of compiling  both.tex
% with option "--enable-write18", then here you can probably insert
% \write18-calls suitable for your platform for calling pdflatex
% from console for compiling the files just generated -- something like:
%
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex A.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex B.tex}
%
% or:
%
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify A.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify B.tex}
%
% or:
%
%    \immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf A.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf B.tex}
%
% If LuaTeX-based LaTeX-engines might also be in use, where no "native"
% `\write18` is available:
%
% \RequirePackage{shellesc} % See: https://ctan.org/pkg/shellesc
% %
% \ShellEscape{latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf A.tex}
% \ShellEscape{latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf B.tex}
% \ShellEscape{latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf A.tex}
% \ShellEscape{latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf B.tex}
% ...
\csname stop\endcsname % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)LaTeX
                       %    for generating the files.
%
\bye % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)TeX for generating the 
%    %    files.
%
%</ignore>
% Section containing the actual LaTeX document, with tags for
% generating different variants
%
%<*A,B>
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstOfOne[1]{#1}
\newcommand*\InterLink[2]{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \hypertarget{\@currentHref.label.#1}{%
%<A>      \hyperref[{FromB:#1}]% If A.pdf shall not contain hyperlinks to B.pdf, do instead: \@firstofone
%<B>      \hyperref[{FromA:#1}]% If B.pdf shall not contain hyperlinks to A.pdf, do instead: \@firstofone
      {#2}%
    }%
    \begingroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@currentHref\expandafter{\@currentHref.label.#1}%
    \label{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }{#2}%
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}
%<A>\externaldocument[FromB:]{B}[./B.pdf]
%<B>\externaldocument[FromA:]{A}[./A.pdf]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{para}{para}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{A section about paras}
%<*A>
\begin{para}
The Kalman filter is an efficient recursive filter that estimates the
internal state of a linear dynamic system from a series of noisy
measurements. It is used in a wide range of engineering and econometric
applications from radar and computer vision to estimation of structural
macroeconomic models, and is an important topic in control theory and
control systems engineering.
\end{para}
\vfill
%</A>
%<*B>
\stepcounter{para}%
%</B>
\begin{para}
%<*A>
Together with the linear-quadratic regulator (LQR), the Kalman filter
solves the linear–quadratic–Gaussian control problem (LQG).
%</A>
\InterLink{para1.2}{%
  The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–
  quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the
  most fundamental problems in control theory.%
}%
\end{para}
\vfill
\begin{para}
\InterLink{para1.3}{%
  In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of
  freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.%
}%
%<*A>
However, by combining a series of measurements, the Kalman filter can
estimate the entire internal state.
%</A>
\end{para}
\vfill
\begin{para}
\InterLink{para1.4}{%
  The symbol \FirstOfOne{\checkmark} comes from amssymb.%
}%
\end{para}
\end{document}
%</A,B>
```

Compiling `both.tex` yields

`A.tex`:

```
%%
%% This is file `A.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% both.tex  (with options: `A')
%% ____________________________
%% 
%% Information relevant to A.tex.
%% 
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstOfOne[1]{#1}
\newcommand*\InterLink[2]{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \hypertarget{\@currentHref.label.#1}{%
      \hyperref[{FromB:#1}]% If A.pdf shall not contain hyperlinks to B.pdf, do instead: \@firstofone
      {#2}%
    }%
    \begingroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@currentHref\expandafter{\@currentHref.label.#1}%
    \label{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }{#2}%
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}
\externaldocument[FromB:]{B}[./B.pdf]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{para}{para}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{A section about paras}
\begin{para}
The Kalman filter is an efficient recursive filter that estimates the
internal state of a linear dynamic system from a series of noisy
measurements. It is used in a wide range of engineering and econometric
applications from radar and computer vision to estimation of structural
macroeconomic models, and is an important topic in control theory and
control systems engineering.
\end{para}
\vfill
\begin{para}
Together with the linear-quadratic regulator (LQR), the Kalman filter
solves the linear–quadratic–Gaussian control problem (LQG).
\InterLink{para1.2}{%
  The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–
  quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the
  most fundamental problems in control theory.%
}%
\end{para}
\vfill
\begin{para}
\InterLink{para1.3}{%
  In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of
  freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.%
}%
However, by combining a series of measurements, the Kalman filter can
estimate the entire internal state.
\end{para}
\vfill
\begin{para}
\InterLink{para1.4}{%
  The symbol \FirstOfOne{\checkmark} comes from amssymb.%
}%
\end{para}
\end{document}
```

`B.tex`:

```
%%
%% This is file `B.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% both.tex  (with options: `B')
%% ____________________________
%% 
%% Information relevant to B.tex.
%% 
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\FirstOfOne[1]{#1}
\newcommand*\InterLink[2]{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \hypertarget{\@currentHref.label.#1}{%
      \hyperref[{FromA:#1}]% If B.pdf shall not contain hyperlinks to A.pdf, do instead: \@firstofone
      {#2}%
    }%
    \begingroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@currentHref\expandafter{\@currentHref.label.#1}%
    \label{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }{#2}%
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}
\externaldocument[FromA:]{A}[./A.pdf]
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{para}{para}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{A section about paras}
\stepcounter{para}%
\begin{para}
\InterLink{para1.2}{%
  The Kalman filter, the linear-quadratic regulator, and the linear–
  quadratic–Gaussian controller are solutions to what arguably are the
  most fundamental problems in control theory.%
}%
\end{para}
\vfill
\begin{para}
\InterLink{para1.3}{%
  In most applications, the internal state is much larger (more degrees of
  freedom) than the few "observable" parameters which are measured.%
}%
\end{para}
\vfill
\begin{para}
\InterLink{para1.4}{%
  The symbol \FirstOfOne{\checkmark} comes from amssymb.%
}%
\end{para}
\end{document}
```

Compiling instructions:

- Compile `A.tex` repetitively. (As `B.tex` isn't compiled yet, there is no `B.aux` yet, thus messages about labels from `B` not being imported won't go away.)
- Compile `B.tex` repetitively.
- Compile `A.tex` repetitively. (This time messages about labels from `B` not being imported won't pop up. `A.aux` might be changed.)
- Compile `B.tex` repetitively. (To make sure changes of `A.aux` are taken into account when importing cross-referencing-labels.)

You get `A.pdf`:

[image]

You get `B.pdf`:

[image]